# How to solve wget errors when reuse sessions

Tags: linux, zsh, wget

I am trying to download the Cityscapes dataset with the following `zsh` script

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt --post-data 'username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&submit=Login' https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/login/
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --content-disposition https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/file-handling/?packageID=1
```

I can successfully download the dataset on the first attempt, but when I want to test the script again, I get the complaint `no matches found: https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/file-handling/?packageID=1`. I guess it is because I am reusing the session.

Comment: don't use the bash tag if you're asking about zsh